# Can not see the awesome font

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, drupal, font-awesome

I add the folder "Font Awesome" on my installation "Drupal 8".

When I load my page, no "Font Awesome" is loaded and there are the following error messeges in the console :

https://www.s1biose.com

```
Refused to execute script from 'https://www.s1biose.com/themes/contrib/bootstrap_subtheme_front_office/fonts/fontawesome/css/all.css?pci27c' because its MIME type ('text/css') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Constructor' of undefined
    at Object.attach (tooltip.js?pci27c:38)
    at drupal.js?v=8.5.5:25
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.Drupal.attachBehaviors (drupal.js?v=8.5.5:22)
    at drupal.init.js?v=8.5.5:16
    at HTMLDocument.t (ready.min.js?v=1.0.8:4)
attach @ tooltip.js?pci27c:38
(anonymous) @ drupal.js?v=8.5.5:25
Drupal.attachBehaviors @ drupal.js?v=8.5.5:22
(anonymous) @ drupal.init.js?v=8.5.5:16
t @ ready.min.js?v=1.0.8:4
setTimeout (async)
Drupal.throwError @ drupal.js?v=8.5.5:12
(anonymous) @ drupal.js?v=8.5.5:27
Drupal.attachBehaviors @ drupal.js?v=8.5.5:22
(anonymous) @ drupal.init.js?v=8.5.5:16
t @ ready.min.js?v=1.0.8:4
```

How can I correct ? I delete all the custom code and it does not work.

Comment: Is it not possible to load font awesome through a style sheet? I don't use drupal but can you not add code to the head, or your stylesheet?

Comment: @joshmoto On "Drupal 8" there is a box "Aggregate JavaScript files" if it is not checked, it works. I do not understand why.

Comment: What does aggregate actually mean? Is aggregate turned off normally?

Comment: @joshmoto the question has changed and I have found an interim solution. Here is the question
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51542354/why-facebook-on-android-blocks-js-content-from-my-site